# Nodemailer using Gmail OAuth2 - Service Acct - Invalid Request Error

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, gmail, nodemailer, google-workspace

Thanks in advance for any help on this one...I'm really stumped. Kind of new with OAuth in general but I've been using nodemailer with Gmail/GSuite for some time now until I got a notice that Google is turning off support for LSA (Less Secure Apps) soon. Keep in mind I'm using a service account because this is for a contact form web service, I do not want to have clients asked for permission every time.

So in my attempts at migrating over to OAuth2, I followed the steps below (in short):

1. In console.developers.google.com, created a new project
2. Enabled Gmail in services for the new project
3. Created new credentials for using a service account, and downloaded secret file

Here's the transporter setup I'm using (straight from nodemailer's docs)

```
//Nodemailer config     
let opt = {
            host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
            port: 465,
            secure: true,
            auth: {
                type: 'OAuth2',
                user: bpsvc.client_email,
                serviceClient: bpsvc.client_id,
                privateKey: bpsvc.private_key
            }
};      

//Nodemailer transporter object
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(opt);
```

The error I'm getting back from the transporter.sendMail() method is as follows:

```
Mon Dec 16 2019 20:20:34 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time) - Transporter sendMail -  { Error: invalid_request
    at postRequest (C:\Source\node\contact\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\xoauth2\index.js:260:33)
    at PassThrough.req.once (C:\Source\node\contact\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\xoauth2\index.js:330:20)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:30)
    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
    at PassThrough.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1055:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9) code: 'EAUTH', command: 'AUTH XOAUTH2' }
```

Now in my troubleshooting attempts, I've tried the following:

- added a console.log to the \node_modules\nodemailer\lib\xoauth2\index.js and the postRequest() method to check the jwt was being created and sent, which it appears to be
- tried changing the endpoint defined in xoauth2\index.js from https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token to https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token but still get the same error

I hope there are some nodemailer/OAuth2/GSuite experts here that can help me find something else to check on. I'm sure it's probably something simple (hopefully).

Comment: After some playing around. Managed to get this to work. However, not as sending as the "service account" email. But rather granting "domain wide access" to the service account. Then going into the admin.google.com / security / trusted apps and adding the service account's client id and the scope to allow access. So I am sending as a normal user, but in the 2LO auth I use the service client_id, and private_key.